# Why cant DFT be implemented this way?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

I am trying to implement the discrete Fourier transform.Here is my code in MATLAB:

```
sym k
n = 1:4;
disp(n);
y = n-2>=0;
z = n-4>=0;
x = y-z;

X(k) = sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*k.*n/4));

l = 1:4;
subplot(1,2,1);
stem(l,abs(X(l)));
subplot(1,2,2);
stem(l,angle(X(l)));
```

I get these results for magnitude and phase:
[image]

However when I try to put the values `[0,1,1,0]` in [this DFT calculator](https://www.easycalculation.com/engineering/mechanical/discrete-fourier-transform.php) I don't get the same results. Where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the 0 frequency. Recall the definition of the DFT:
$$X[k] = \sum_{n =0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi \frac{k}{N}n}\quad\quad k = 0, 1, \dots, N-1$$

```
n = 1:4;
y = n-2>=0;
z = n-4>=0;
x = y-z;

for k = 1:4
   X(k) = sum(x .* exp(-1j*2*pi*(k-1).*(n-1)/4)); 
end
```

gives the correct result.

Comment: But it doesnt let me do it it hits a error at "X(k) = sum(x .* exp(-1j*2*pi*(k-1).*(n-1)/4));"

Comment: It has to do with the fact that it treats k as symbolic variable so k-1 isnt correct.

Comment: Why are you using `sym k`, just use the code I provided, that's what the DFT is.

Comment: It still doesnt get compiled.

Comment: Yes it does maybe if I restart the MATLAB the issue gets solved.

Comment: I don't have the symbolic math toolbox, but alternatively, with `sym k;` and
    
    `X(k) = sum(x .* exp(-1j*2*pi*k.*(n-1)/4));` and  
   `l = 0:3;`
it should also work. Can you confirm?

Comment: Wait one minute to check...

Comment: Nope stem doesnt accept it.In Matlab when indexing a array you start from 1 so if you set l  = 0:3 it produces compile error.

Comment: hmm no `stem` isn't the issue. Anyways, glad I could help ;)