# Matlab's FFT wrong?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, fourier-transform

In my  [previous question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86333/why-cant-dft-be-implemented-this-way), I tried to implement the DFT. Now I want to compare it to Matlab's FFT

My input signal is:

```
x(n) = n-2>=0
```

Here are the results:
[image]

As you see, my DFT doesn't match Matlab's results.

[This](https://www.easycalculation.com/engineering/mechanical/discrete-fourier-transform.php) online calculator agrees with my snippet of code. What is going on?

Comment: So, what's the difference between the two? I would try to find another solution for the riddle than the option that Matlab's FFT has a bug.

Comment: @MattL. as you can see the phase shift is different.

Comment: @Volpina: is it really? What's the difference ?

Comment: @Volpina: OK, I can see what you see, but I don't agree that there's an actual difference. Hint: $-1=e^{j\pi}=e^{-j\pi}$

Comment: I see the difference is 2π radians so it is essentially the same.

Comment: It's not at all about the FFT/DFT, it's just about how we define the function 'angle' for negative numbers, and both definitions are fine, because they don't make any difference.

Comment: @Volpina: You got it ...